# Contentversion getBodyAsBlob issue

Tags: rest-api, contentversion, blob.topdf

I'm tried to insert contentversion record from API response. In response getting PDF only. I've tried below code but i'm having issue in previewing the file.

```
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
blob image = response.getBodyAsBlob();
cv.VersionData = image;
cv.PathOnClient = Sample; 
cv.title = Sample; 
cv.origin = 'H';
insert cv;
```

Same response I tried to insert as Attachment. Its working fine.

```
Attachment objAttachment = new Attachment();
objAttachment.Body =  response.getBodyAsBlob(); 
objAttachment.ParentId = '132435454';
objAttachment.Name = 'Test';
objAttachment.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
insert objAttachment;
```

Please advise me what I missed in ContentVersion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have skipped the extension part in Contentversion. You need to give file title name with extension.

```
cv.title = Sample+'.pdf';
```

[ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)

Comment: Thanks for reply. We have add to cv.PathOnClient = Sample+'.pdf';  then only its work without issue.

Comment: @user10286 then you can accept the answer and close the question.